# Saving and Relodaing ListView entries

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

I am creating an app similar to a note taking app ( still new to this ) When I add entries to my listview I want them to be saved in storage when i close my app via the home button and back press. And when i start my app I want my previous entries to be loaded. My code is below

```
EditText forest;
TextView tv;
TextView date;
Button btn;
ListView txtlist;
public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayAdapter<String> add;
private NotesDataSource datasource;
String Lrg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_track);

    datasource = new NotesDataSource(this);

    txtlist = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    forest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.trackedit);

    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tracktxt1);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.trackbtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}
    private void saveAndFinish(){

```
        forest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.trackedit);
        String Lrg = forest.getText().toString();

         list.add(0, Lrg);
         KoreyzAdapter add = new KoreyzAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
         setListAdapter(add);
         add.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        saveAndFinish();
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    saveAndFinish();
}


public void onClick(View v) {

    String Lrg = forest.getText().toString();

    if(Lrg.trim().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter an Argument Topic!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
        }else{
     list.add(0, Lrg);
     KoreyzAdapter add = new KoreyzAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
     setListAdapter(add);
     add.notifyDataSetChanged();
     forest.setText("");
        }
}
static class ViewHolder{
  TextView gump;
  ImageView pic;
  TextView day;
  ImageView more;

  ViewHolder(View v){
      gump = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.inputLrgtxt);
      pic = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.sexpic);
      day = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.holla);
  }

}
private class KoreyzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

      private ArrayList<String> list;
      private Context context;

      public KoreyzAdapter(Context c, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> list) {
          super(c, textViewResourceId, list);
          this.list = list;
          this.context = c;
      }


          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            long msTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Date date = new Date(msTime);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/y");
            String biggie = sdf.format(date);

            if(row == null){

                 LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                  row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                  holder = new ViewHolder(row);
                  row.setTag(holder);

            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
            }

                holder.gump.setText(list.get(position));
                holder.day.setText(biggie);

                  return row;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check available data storage in Android Platform. You can save your data in storage before finish and on start can fetch your entries and load on screen.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist your data using an SQLite database or something similar.

Basically you would need to:

1. When creating a new item, save it to SQLite database
2. When your app is (re)started you fetch all items from your database
3. When initializing the `ListView` attach an `Adapter` that you feed your list of items

For example, see this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: yes i have that website bookmarked alot of good information but i was thinking more along the lines of local data storage

Comment: SQLite **is** local storage. How do you mean?

Comment: It's a bit hard to show here in the comments or as an SO answer, but have a look at this project I created some time ago, and this class in particular: https://github.com/slidese/BabyFeed/blob/master/src/se/slide/babyfeed/LogFragment.java

Comment: @LimpLimp, did it help you? If so, please tick the answer.

Comment: thanks for the insight but i already knew of the process and sqlite and the website i have it book marked and i refer to it often.